# i have this error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel

controller
two functions

```
public function get_login(){
return view('login');
}
public function post_login(){
$user = ['email'=>request('email'),'password',request('password')] ;
$re = request()->has('remember')?true:false;
if(auth()->attempt($user,$re )
{
    return redirect('home');
}else {
}}
```

model

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'name','email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = admin@admin.com and `0` = password and `1` = admin limit 1)

Comment: This line is a typo: `$user = ['email'=>request('email'),'password',request('password')];` it should be `'password' => $request('password')`

Comment: thanks a lot ..it was my mistake add ',' instead of '=>'

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake when declaring your login details. You are supposed to use an associative array and not a mixed array. So you should change from:

```php
$user = ['email'=>request('email'),'password',request('password')] ;
```

to

```php
$user = ['email'=>request('email'),'password' => request('password')] ;
```

basically it means replace that comma after `password` with a fat arrow `=>`

Answer (score 0):

test this:

```
$user = $request->only('email','password') ;
```

instead

```
$user = ['email'=>request('email'),'password',request('password')] ;
```